# SMS Status Codes in _SMSMessageTracking having 4504 FailedDueToUnknownSubscriber when Journey Builder SMS sent

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms, data-views, sendsmsactivity

I use Journey Builder SMS sent and for some small amount of subscribers I had 4504 FailedDueToUnknownSubscriber in the field SMS Status Codes in _SMSMessageTracking according [to this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/sms-status-codes.html). Because there is limited explaination on how this happend, I am unable to go further towards the root cause.

I hope to receive any insight from your experience regarding this matter. Thank you very much

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you described but I believe this error due to the mobile number does not exist or no longer active. You would want to check if the mobile numbers were correct for these subscribers

Comment: Thanks @Duc Le for your input, I got a few contacts having mobile number not existing or no longer active as well but they will have either 4500 Undeliverable, 4505 FailedDueToInvalidDestinationAddress or 4503 Rejected. I opened a case to salesforce support, but they couldn't find more official documents for it besides the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce support advised that there is no official documentation for these errors however they said that we can have a look at sinch (Salesforce SMS partner's document) https://developers.sinch.com/docs/sms/smpp/error-codes/.

Salesforce will receive the sms error code from sinch. After a call with support from Salesforce, they confirmed that 4504 FailedDueToUnknownSubscriber is a permanent error coresponding to Sinch's 150    HLR ERROR   Unknown subscriber. Message is rejected because there is no directory number for the mobile subscriber.

We concluded that this error is from the mobile number not exist or invalid